# CSS blend modes

Tags: css

I am trying to design a tshirt using CSS blend modes. I have tried what i could but Is there a better way to create this design using CSS blend modes so that the baby image blend in with the tshirt image?

https://codepen.io/akin-orisajobi/pen/JZBPBz

```css
.tshirt-design {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/d1TwN8/baby1_resized.png), url("https://image.ibb.co/ifxRpo/crew_front.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px 150px, contain;
  background-position: 120px 70px, 0 0;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="tshirt-design">
</div>
```

Comment: it depends on the result you want to have

Comment: What's wrong with your approach?